# C: variable with random value debugger error

Tags: debugging, random, error-handling

In a function I have a local variable which is initialized at the beginning. Further in the code this variable is "filled" with a random value, generated with rand()
It doesn't work and the debugger tells me:

> ```
>   random_color_value  Failed getting location list for symbol die# 0x4b9  Error
> ```

This is a snippet of the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
.
.
.
struct cRGB colorFade(void){    
    uint8_t random_color_value; 
   .
   .
   .        
   srand(2);
   random_color_value = rand() % 12 +1; // generate random value between 1 and 12 (including 12) 
   .
   .
   . 
}
```

The compiler inside my AVR-Studio is set to optimize for size.
What could cause that problem?

Comment: `uint8_t random_color_value; ` this is not initialised and I do not know what code is `....`

Comment: Hi Ed, Ok, the variable is set up but initializing it with any value doesn't make a difference.
The rest of the code is not important for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The initialization of the variable had to be done globally to avoid that the variable is instantiated each time the function is called.